# Interceptors with StructureMap and Fluent NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, structuremap, interceptor

I have successfully configured StrctureMap and FluentNHibernate to work together with a parameter-less constructor. What I need to do now is set the interceptor with parameters.

The following code below works well in my MVC application:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{ 
    //Code removed from here to save space...

    ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => {
        x.For<IInterceptor>().Singleton().Use(context => new MyInterceptor());

        x.For<ISessionFactory>().Singleton().Use(context => CreateSessionFactory(context.GetInstance<IInterceptor>()));
        x.For<ISession>().HttpContextScoped().Use(context => context.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());

        x.For<IAuditDao>().Use<AuditDao>().Ctor<ISessionFactory>().Is(context => context.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>());
    });
}

public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory(IInterceptor interceptor)
{
    return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MySQLConfiguration
        .Standard
        .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("MySqlConnectionString")))
        .Mappings(m => { m.FluentMappings.Add<AuditItemMap>(); })
        .ExposeConfiguration(config => new SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(true, true))
        .ExposeConfiguration(config => config.SetInterceptor(interceptor))
        .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

What I now need to do is pass an instance of AuditDao into the the interceptor. At the moment 'MyInterceptor' which inherits from the NHibernate 'EmptyInterceptor' has two constructors:

```
public class MyInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    private IAuditDao AuditDao;

    public MyInterceptor()
    {

    }

    public MyInterceptor(IAuditDao auditDao)
    {
        AuditDao = auditDao;
    }
}
```

Now obviously an instance of AuditDao needs an instance of SessionFactory and SessionFactory would need an instance of AuditDao.

How do I solve this circular reference problem?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question or figure it out?